# How to set default SMS App in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean

It is possible to set it in Android 4.4 KitKat. But how can I set it in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean?
After installing Tango I fell in this problem.

Comment: Uninstall it, or go to Settings > Applications > Tango > Remove Defaults and then select a new default SMS and dialer appliction. There should be a setting in your SMS app but I have no idea what phone you have. You can aslo go into Hangouts settings and set it as default SMS.

Comment: I have Sony Xperia Z Ultra. I don't want to uninstall it. I need Tango.
I couldn't find where you told. I couldn't find a place in my phone to set default SMS application.

Comment: In Android 4.4, it is possible: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/manage-default-sms-app-on-android-4-4-kitkat/
but how to in Android 4.2?

Comment: In settings->app->Downloaded->Tango->Clear default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

In Android 4.2 Jelly Bean, We should manage default app in same app we don't want it to handle SMS.

In Tango 3 settings, there is an option to avoid SMS handling.